# Can I add a moving scale or axis in plots using Vegalite?

Tags: d3.js, vega-lite

I am trying to add a movable scale or axis inside a plot. For instance: in this example of stacked plot: [Click-to-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9G0m.png)

I want to include a movable y-axis scale so, if we hover the graph and put the mouse pointer on the beginning of the orange color of any bar, the a-xis will begin from that bar. (Specifically, moving x=0 line.)
I meant something like this example (of d3).
https://observablehq.com/@d3/index-chart
But, here I want to change the value of x-axis by moving the line. Is it possible to do it using vegalite? If somebody has any similar example in vegalite, can you refer it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no animation in Vega Lite. However, you may check out [Gemini](https://github.com/uwdata/gemini) which aims to extend the grammar of data viz to some simple animations of **single-view** Vega/Vega-Lite charts